# how to fix ruby bundle install error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Everytime I try to run `bundle install` inside a local copy of this RoR [project](https://github.com/catarse/catarse) directory, I get an error. I have rvm installed with ruby 2.1.2 and 2.2.2, rails is installed as well. I am running via vagrant on this [box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64), Ubuntu 14.04 with 1gb of ram tho I don't think any of this is relevant? I can't seem to find the missing file the error is pointing to as well?

Update: Here is the Gemfile

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.6'

#gem 'catarse_api', path: '~/code/catarse_api'
gem 'catarse_api', github: 'catarse/catarse_api'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'

gem 'sidekiq',  '~> 3.1.3'

# Turns every field on a editable one
gem "best_in_place", :git => "git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place", ref: "ee95961e639022e6aa528704b8cb4789596ea61b"

# State machine for attributes on models
gem 'state_machine', require: 'state_machine/core'

# Database and data related
gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
gem 'dbhero', '>= 1.1.6'
gem 'postgres-copy'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'i18n_alchemy'

gem 'schema_plus'
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'catarse_settings_db', '>= 0.1.0'

# Notifications
gem 'user_notifier', '~> 0.0.5'

# Mixpanel for backend tracking
gem 'mixpanel-ruby'
gem 'mixpanel_client'

# Payment engines
gem 'catarse_moip', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'catarse_pagarme', '2.6.8'
#gem 'catarse_pagarme', path: '../catarse_pagarme'

# Decorators
gem 'draper'

# Frontend stuff
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'browser'
gem "cocoon"

# Static pages
gem 'high_voltage'

# Authentication and Authorization
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'devise'
gem 'ezcrypto'
gem 'pundit'

# Email marketing
gem 'catarse_monkeymail', '>= 0.1.6'

# HTML manipulation and formatting
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mail_form'
gem "auto_html"
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'redactor-rails', github: 'catarse/redactor-rails'

# Uploads
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem "mini_magick"

# Other Tools
gem 'to_xls'
gem 'ranked-model'
gem 'feedjira'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'has_scope', '>= 0.6.0.rc'
gem 'spectator-validates_email',  require: 'validates_email'
gem 'video_info', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.6.1' # this version is required by moip gem, otherwise payment confirmation will break

# Translations
gem 'http_accept_language'
gem 'routing-filter', '~> 0.4.0.pre'

# Payment
gem 'moip', github: 'catarse/moip-ruby', ref: 'c0225ad71645cd1df35dafa1e45c9f092b3abb9e'
gem 'httpclient',     '>= 2.2.5'

group :production do
  # Gem used to handle image uploading
  gem 'fog', '>= 1.3.1'

  # Workers, forks and all that jazz
  gem 'unicorn'

  # Enabling Gzip on Heroku
  # If you don't use Heroku, please comment the line below.
  gem 'heroku-deflater', '>= 0.4.1'

  # Make heroku serve static assets and loggin with stdout
  #gem 'rails_on_heroku'
  gem 'rails_12factor'

  # Monitoring with the new new relic
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'

  # Using dalli and memcachier have not presented significative performance gains
  # Probably this is due to our pattern of cache usage
  # + the lack of concurrent procs in our deploy
  #gem 'memcachier'
  #gem 'dalli'
end
group :development do
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'thin'
  # Uncomment only for optimization, should be commented on master branch
  # gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  # gem 'ruby-prof'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'rspec-mocks'
  gem 'rspec-its'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'zonebie'
  gem 'fakeweb'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara',   '~> 2.2.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'compass-960-plugin'
gem 'sprockets'

# FIXME: Not-anymore-on-development
# Gems that are with 1 or more years on the vacuum
gem 'weekdays'
```

ps: please point out any relevant info i should provide as well to help determine the cause.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/390.

Comment: He's not using rails 4.2. Try installing bundler?  gem install bundler?

Comment: @osman If you read the thread, it seems to be an issue with the GEM_PATH, which may or may not have to do with Rails but does seem to apply in this case. Also, OP tagged the question RoR and indicated that Rails is installed. While he didn't specify the version, based on the specific error message, I'd wager that he is indeed on 4.2.

Comment: @osman Rails 4.2 is installed, i Just checked. and bundler is also installed. other wise i think it would output a different message saying bundle can't be found?

Comment: @MarsAtomic i've added my gemfile, and checked the link you posted tho i still couldn't solve the issue. any idea what might I do ?

Comment: what's at /usr/bin/bundle line 7?

Comment: another thing to look at is: ruby-2.2.2 but site_ruby is picking up from 2.2.0. So guessing that something is busted in the GEM_PATH as @MarsAtomic is pointing out above

Comment: @Nour I'm sorry, I'm no expert on Vagrant and Rails. I just found a related issue for you to use. I'm in no position to be of further assistance, other than to encourage you to follow that thread, since a number of its participants seem to have solved their problem.

Comment: @Mircea i just checked the file, this is line 7 [ require 'bundler' ] , I've installed ruby 2.2.0 via RVM and changed it to default as well, tho it didn't work out

Comment: I solved this just now, by doing the following after i checked the bundle file pointed out by @Mircea , i ran this [ gem cleanup bundler ] and then re installed it, that seemed to solve the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there was an issue with bundler, here's how this worked out for me:

- cleanup by running `gem cleanup bundler`
- reinstall bundler via `gem install bundler`